# MVC Download File from Remote Server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to download file from Remote Server but I am running up with errors.

```
public ActionResult Download()
{
    var a = new Uri("file://<<REMOTE_SERVER>>/<<Folder>>/Test.csv");
    return File(a, "application/csv", "test.csv");
}
```

Error:

```
file://<<REMOTE_SERVER>>/<<Folder>>/Test.csv is not a valid virtual path.
```

Comment: Are remote server and folder supposed to be variables?

Comment: @AndrewKilburn, Not Variables, It will be having values..

Comment: Are you sure about the "file://"? you should be using another protocol, file:// is for local files only

Comment: I am trying to access with this protocol in browser and it downloading the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using System.Security.Principal;          

using (new Impersonator("myUsername", "myDomainname", "myPassword"))
          {
             return File(@"<<REMOTE_SERVER>>\<<Folder>>\Test.csv", "application/csv", "test.csv");
          }
```

If you add the @ sign it will disable any escape characters. Besides you only have one / in the middle of your path which is why it isn't valid.

Look here for more info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w070t6ka(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Okay, is it still the same error? Then I believe the path is probably incorrect then. Can you copy the path and paste it in the document explorer to bring you to the required file?

Comment: It is working, but it is asking for credentials and how to pass that?

Comment: I think you'll have to impersonate a user and pass through the credentials? I'll update my answer now

Comment: What imports do I need to use for Impersonator?

Comment: using System.Security.Principal; <-- That

Comment: There is not such method inside Impersonator. I think something needs to done with WindowsIdentiy

Comment: Look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w070t6ka(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try using a direct path:

```
var a = "\\\<<REMOTE_SERVER>>\\<<Folder>>\\Test.csv";
return File(a, "application/csv", "test.csv");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[HttpGet]
public EmptyResult DownloadAttachment()        
{
    var filePath = "http://img.local.com/Images/Customers/15364053/Inv_LMEM1LA6543_1.png";

    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        byte[] imageData = client.DownloadData(filePath);

        string contentType = "";
        if (fileName.ToLower().Contains(".png"))
        {
            contentType = "Images/png";
        }
        else if (fileName.ToLower().Contains(".jpg"))
        {
            contentType = "Images/jpg";
        }
        else if (fileName.ToLower().Contains(".jpeg"))
        {
            contentType = "Images/jpeg";
        }
        else if (fileName.ToLower().Contains(".pdf"))
        {
            contentType = "Images/pdf";
        }
        else if (fileName.ToLower().Contains(".tiff"))
        {
            contentType = "Images/tiff";
        }

        Response.ContentType = contentType;
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
        Response.ContentType = "image/JPEG";
        Response.OutputStream.Write(imageData, 0, imageData.Length);
        Response.End();

    }
    return new EmptyResult();
}
```

Comment: Could you explain your answer as well?